# Cant upgrade Ubuntu from 16.04 to 18.04-Hash sum mismatch

Tags: 16.04, upgrade, 18.04

I'm unable to upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04
All the packages get downloaded but then this error pops up:
[dialog box that shows the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ujGU2.png)
 It says "Could not download the upgrades The upgrade has aborted. Please check your Internet connection or installation media and try again. All files downloaded so far have been kept."
and "Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/freepats/freepats_20060219-1_all.deb Hash Sum mismatch
"

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by installing freepats from [debian package for freepats](http://ftp.tw.debian.org/debian/pool/main/f/freepats/freepats_20060219-1_all.deb)